# Linking my Heroku app to GitHub

Tags: heroku, github

I have an app on Heroku and I want to link it to github. I've tried some suggestions found on here.  For example

```
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:<app name>.git
```

but I get

> fatal: remote heroku already exists.

What do I need to do?

Comment: Weird, your command suggests you're trying to name your new remote `geroku`, whereas the error message suggests git thought you were trying to name your new remote `heroku`. What does your `git remote -v` display?

Comment: sorry, that was a typo. I did `add heroku` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku waits for a new push from Github before deploying. You have to first push to Github, and then connect your repository to Heroku.
[image]

Comment: When I try to push I get a rejection and I am asked to `Integrate the remote changes (e.g.hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.` That also fails (`error: Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files.`). Not sure how to merge!

Comment: @MartaP. You need to add your Guthub repository, not Heroku. You're pushing changes to Github and Heroku is seeing those changes and then deploying. See this article about adding Github remotes: [https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote/](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote/)